# make a .flv from a bunch of jpeg-s

Tags: linux, video, images, flv

I have a bunch of jpeg and want to make a single flv video file from it.

I need flv/mp4 (vp6/h264 codecs).

Could you please tell me how to do it?

It must be done via console command on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont have ffmpeg to try but...

**Join images to movie**

> First, rename your pictures to follow a numerical sequence. For example, img1.jpg, img2.jpg, img3.jpg,... Then you may run:
>
> `ffmpeg -f image2 -i img%d.jpg /tmp/a.mpg`
>
> Notice that `%d` is replaced by the image number.

[read more](http://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html#SEC14)

**Convert mpg to flv**
`ffmpeg -i <input-file> -acodec mp3 -ar 11025 -f flv -s 320x240 -y <output-file>`

I suspect you can skip the two step process and convert directly to flv in the first step but can't experiment on this computer.